# jQuery UI datepicker shows text input instead of date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use the following method to use jQuery UI date picker, adding the `<script>` to the `<head>` and the `input` in the `body`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      minDate: "+2D",
      maxDate: "+24D",
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false
    });
  });
</script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

This code doesn't show any datepicker, and it is simple text input. I try to change the jQuery version to 3.5.1 but still no different.

Since it works on a blank HTML page, I am sure there is a conflict with other codes, How should I find the reason of this problem or conflict?

Comment: are you seeing any error inside browser console ?

Comment: Thanks @Swati , in console there is an error : `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).slick is not a function TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function` this error can cause problem?

Comment: That error is not related to datepicker . Try moving your script tags before `</body>` see if that works .

Comment: Yes, I already put it in `<head>` section then I move it to `<body>` , but surprisingly still no different.

Comment: The problem was solved, I use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` two times.